# Vectorize multiplication by different constants

Tags: performance, numpy, vectorization

I'm trying to multiply various matrices by constants, and usually vectorizing makes things like this faster, but I can't quite figure this one out. Let's say I'm doing a polynomial expansion and I have a list of constants for different functions.

```
    for i in range(10):
        expansions[i,:,:] += c[i,k]*(matrix)
```

Now, this is the simple way to do it, but I was wondering if there was some way to do it like this:

```
        expansions[:,:,:] += c[:,k]*(matrix)
```

Where I apply each constant individually to "matrix". I tried to stack lots of "matrix" on top of itself, to create something of size (10xNxN), but this didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using `np.einsum`?

Comment: `np.multiply.outer(c[:,k],matrix)`?